# Refiner showing on 15 items

Tags: search, managed-metadata, refiner

In my search refiner I am getting on 15 Item and sorting also not working.
Even after I have changed Maximum number limit to 999.
And Sort by: Name, Direction: Ascending

Comment: hidden refiner for same property was creating problem